# writing user management with sessions or cookies in ASP.NET MVC 3 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, user-management

hello im new at c# and asp.net mvc 3 also.
Im trying to make an alternative user management (log in, log out etc.), I have tried session and cookie but i think i couldn't so i decided to ask here.
my user informations are stored in sql server database's table "users" and im using EF.
i can not change table design so i need to do a system that it can handle this stuation.

please give me examples ( how can i do ) i read some membership's profile thing, can i use it with this EF?

thanks

Comment: why are you trying to reinvent the wheel when you are brand new to the technology? Just create a membership provider and let the existing system handle the logins.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the Membership providers out of the box with EF yet. Universal providers for ASP.NET are coming. see [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) for more information

Comment: in real, i dont wanna use asp.net administrator site, i was a php guy but in this project i have to use asp.net how can i do this with session or cookie i will store isLoggedin and LoginID variables in them.